# How to print Appendix A like Chapter 1

Tags: formatting, scrbook

I get Chapter 1 Name of Chapter.

But how to get Appendix A Name of appendix

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  Chapter~\fontsize{80}{88}\selectfont\thechapter\enskip}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Name of chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Name of appendix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\@chapapp` contains the proper string "Chapter" or "Appendix" (or their idiomatic localization):

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \@chapapp~\fontsize{80}{88}\selectfont\thechapter\enskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Name of chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{Name of appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]